# Creating a custom button in android in the xml layout

Tags: android, button, customization, android-xml

I am trying to change the style of android default buttons. I have created an xml file in the drawable folder in res folder called `custom_button.xml` and have referenced it in the xml layout file, however when I run the application, the button style has not changed and instead I have lost the outline of the original button.

**`custom_button.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <solid
        android:color="#FF0000" /> 
</shape>
```

**`main.xml`**

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#6600ff"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_getDraw"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_getDraw"
        android:onClick="getLotteryDrawFromWebsite" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_check"
        android:onClick="checkNumbers"
        android:enabled="false" />
```

Whats the problem? Thx in advance..

Answer (score 3):

Change your custom_button xml to this .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="#FF0000"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this [link](http://undertowsam.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/design-custom-background-and-button-for-android-using-xml/)....
also you set button selection effect.